# Use feeder value in repeat function gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

How can I use a feeder value in my repeat function?
I would send the request 10 times and after that 20 times.
Is there another way to do this dynamically?

This code is not executing requests. What's going wrong?

CSV:

```
username,count
foo,10
bar,20
```

Gatling code:

```
val times = 0;
private val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation").feed(csvFeeder)
  .exec {
    session =>
      times = session("count").as[Int]
      println(times)
      session
  }
  .repeat(times) {
    exec(http(s"request").get("https://test.com"))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The call `repeat(times)` reads the variable only once, when the test was initialized. I.e. when the value was 0, way before you change it with the [session hook](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#exec).

`repeat` can take an EL string, which retrieves the value from the `Session`.
The following example is from the documentation.

https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#repeat

```scala
// with a Gatling EL string resolving an Int
repeat("#{times}") {
  exec(http("name").get("/"))
}
```